# JSON Deserialization issue with Ziptastic

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

```
public class ZiptasticAPIResponse
{
    [JsonPropertyName("country")]
    public string country { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("state")]
    public string DefaultState { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("city")]
    public string DefaultCity { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("citiesList")]
    public List<CitiesList> CitiesList { get; set; }
}

var url = _alternateURL + zip;
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), url))
{
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var ziptasticResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ZiptasticAPIResponse>(content);                   
    ziptasticResponse.CitiesList = new List<CitiesList>()
    {
        new CitiesList()
        {
            State=ziptasticResponse.DefaultCity,City=ziptasticResponse.DefaultCity
        }
    };

    return ziptasticResponse.CitiesList;
```

I am getting null for DefaultCity and DefaultState but my country is 'US'

when I enter the url in my browser, I get the entire city, state

```
 https://ziptasticapi.com/90210
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What's the actual JSON? Your code is using `DefaultCity`, not `country` so it doesn't matter that `country` contains `US`. Does `DefaultCity` contain anything?

Comment: I don't need the country for anything. I just need the city and state to prepopulate the form when they are filling it out. However when they enter a zipcode, it's coming back as null. I dont know why. The browser is showing data when I type the address

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos DefaultCity and DefaultState are my local values in C#. The server does have values. DefaultCity should be "BEVERLY HILLS" (if you use the url above) and DefaultState will be "CA"

Comment: Perhaps your problem is caused by the fact that you are mixing attributes and methods from different serializers.  The attribute [`JsonPropertyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute) is from System.Text.Json but you are using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` from Json.NET to deserialize your JSON string.  If you want to deserialize using Json.NET, use [`Newtonsoft.JsonJsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) instead.

Comment: @dbc your comment solved my problem. Can you post it as an answer so I can credit you?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by the fact that you are mixing attributes and methods from different serializers.  The attribute [`JsonPropertyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute) is from System.Text.Json but you are using [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) from Json.NET to deserialize your JSON string.  You need to use attributes and methods from the same serializer consistently.

**If you want to deserialize using Json.NET**, annotate your model with  [`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) instead of `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName`:

```
public class ZiptasticAPIResponse
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("country")]
    public string country { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("state")]
    public string DefaultState { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("city")]
    public string DefaultCity { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("citiesList")]
    public List<CitiesList> CitiesList { get; set; }
}
```

And the later

```
var ziptasticResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ZiptasticAPIResponse>(content);
```

**If you would prefer to use `System.Text.Json` in .NET 5.0** you may use [`HttpClientJsonExtensions.GetFromJsonAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.getfromjsonasync?view=net-5.0) and leave `ZiptasticAPIResponse` unchanged:

```
var url = _alternateURL + zip;
try
{
    var ziptasticResponse = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<ZiptasticAPIResponse>(url);
    return ziptasticResponse;
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex) // Request failed.
{
    // Check status code
    var statusCode = ex.StatusCode;
    Console.WriteLine(statusCode);
}
catch (JsonException) // Malformed JSON
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid JSON.");
}
catch (NotSupportedException)
{
    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0#handle-errors
    Console.WriteLine("The content type is not application/json.");
}
// handle other exceptions or let them be handled at some higher level.
```

No matter which you choose, you might want to avoid mixing `using Newtonsoft.Json.*` and `using System.Text.Json.*` using statements in any given file.  It's easy to make this mistake as the Newtonsoft and System.Text.Json attributes have very similar, and sometimes identical, names.

Demo fiddle for System.Text.Json [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NSA7Dw).